# Resampling dataset for spam classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification, resampling

I have a class imbalance problem with the following dataset:

```
Text                             is_it_capital?     is_it_upper?      contains_num?   Label
an example of text                      0                  0               0            0
ANOTHER example of text                 1                  1               0            1
What's happening?Let's talk at 5        1                  0               1            1
```

and similar. I have 5000 rows/texts (4500 with class 0 and 500 with class 1).

I would need to re-sample my classes, but I do not know where to include this step in my model, so I would appreciate if you could have a look and tell me if I am missing some step or if you spot any inconsistencies in the approach.

For train, test I am using the following:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=40)
```

Where `X` is

```
X=df[['Text','is_it_capital?', 'is_it_upper?', 'contains_num?']]
y=df['Label']

df_train= pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
df_test = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)


# Separating classes

spam = df_train[df_train.Label == 1]
not_spam = df_train[df_train.Label == 0]

# Oversampling  

oversampl = resample(spam,replace=True,n_samples=len(not_spam), random_state=42)

oversampled = pd.concat([not_spam, oversampl])
df_train = oversampled.copy()
```

Output (wrong?):

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.94      0.98      0.96      3600
         1.0       0.76      0.52      0.62       400

    accuracy                           0.93      4000
   macro avg       0.86      0.77      0.80      4000

weighted avg       0.92      0.93      0.93      4000
```

Do you think there is something wrong in my steps for oversampling the dataset as confusion matrix gives me a support of 400 and not higher?

Sorry for the long post, but I think it is worthy to report all the steps for a better understanding of the approach I have taken.

Comment: It looks like you didn't use the `oversampled` variable to train your model. I think this line `logR_pipeline.fit(df_train['Text'], df_train['Label'])` should be `logR_pipeline.fit(oversampled['Text'], oversampled['Label'])`.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what is the question you want an answer for. Do you seek advice as how to use oversampling ? Or advice on how to train your model ? How familiar are you with machine learning ?

Comment: Please make an executable example. I feel like key part of your code are missing, `build_confusion_matrix` is not defined, the `c` parameter is unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your method and it's normal that the evaluation report shows imbalanced data. This is because:

- The resampling is (rightly) done on the training set only, in order to force the model to give more importance to the minority class.
- The evaluation is (rightly) made on the test set which follows the original imbalanced distribution. It would be a mistake to resample the test set as well, because the evaluation must be done [on the true distribution of the data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15630/64377).